# When the identity is the least non-constant

Tags: set-theory, filters

In the Handbook of Set Theory, what is the order on the page $25$ -$3$rd line $\leq$
and how can I see that $(\text{id}_U)$ is in the domain of $\pi$ ?
Here $\pi$ is a collapsing isomorphism of the upltrapower onto its transitive collapse.
Finally how do I apply  Łoś's Theorem to obtain $$\kappa\leq \pi((\text{id}_U))<j(\kappa)$$ ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Ult}{\operatorname{Ult}}$
$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$
Recall that $\Ult(V,U)$ is the class of equivalence class $[f]$ of functions $f : \kappa \to V$ such that $[f] = [g]$ iff $f$ agreed with $g$ on a set in the ultrafilter $U$. Here, by $\pi((\id)_U)$ the text means $\pi([\id]_U)$, where $\id(\alpha) = \alpha$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$.

To see that the identity you mentioned holds:

1. For all $\alpha < \kappa$, $\alpha < \id(\gamma) = \gamma$ on the set $\{\gamma < \kappa : \alpha < \gamma\}$. This set has complement of size $<\kappa$, so it is in $U$ as $U$ is $\kappa$-complete. In other words:
   $$
   \{\alpha < \kappa : \alpha < \id(\gamma)\} \in U
   $$
   Let $c_\alpha$ be the function such that $c_\alpha(\beta) = \alpha$ for all $\beta$. Then Łos' Theorem asserts that for all $\alpha < \kappa$:
   $$
   \Ult(V,U) \models [c_\alpha]_U < [\id]_U
   $$
   Recall that $j(\alpha) = [c_\alpha]_U$, by the definition of the elementary embedding $j$. Since $\kappa$ is the least ordinal moved, $j(\alpha) = \alpha$. In other words, we have that:
   $$
   \Ult(V,U) \models \forall \alpha < \kappa(\alpha < [\id]_U)
   $$
   Hence $\Ult(V,U) \models \kappa \leq [\id]_U$.
2. $\id(\alpha) < \kappa$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$. In particular:
   $$
   \{\alpha < \kappa : \id(\alpha) < \kappa\} \in U
   $$
   By Łos' Theorem:
   $$
   \Ult(V,U) \models [\id]_U < [c_\kappa]_U = j(\kappa)
   $$

Since $\pi$ is an isomorphism, we have that:
$$
\pi(\kappa) \leq \pi([\id]_U) < \pi(j(\kappa))
$$
But $\pi(\kappa) = \kappa$ and $\pi(j(\kappa)) = j(\kappa)$ as they are ordinals.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Ult}{\operatorname{Ult}}$
$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$ Why intuitively have we lost the strict inequality and got a weak one here: Hence $\Ult(V,U) \models \kappa \leq [\id]_U$ ?

Comment: For any ordinal $\lambda$, the assertion "$\kappa \leq \lambda$" is equivalent to "$\forall \alpha < \kappa(\alpha < \lambda)$".

Comment: One more problem: How does $[c_\kappa]_U$ match $\kappa$ in this formulas: $$
\{\alpha < \kappa : \id(\alpha) < \kappa\} \in U
$$
By Łos' Theorem:
$$
\Ult(V,U) \models [\id]_U < [c_\kappa]_U = j(\kappa)
$$ ? Why these are equivalent and correspond to each other ?

Comment: Given two functions $f,g : \kappa \to V$, we have that $\operatorname{Ult}(V,U) \models [f]_U < [g]_U$ iff $\{\alpha < \kappa : f(\alpha) < g(\alpha)\} \in U$. Now observe that $c_\kappa(\alpha) = \kappa$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$.

Comment: And why is $$[c_\kappa]_U=j(\kappa)$$ ?

Comment: The definition of the embedding is precisely $j(x) = [c_x]_U$ for all $x \in V$.